# bash: declare variable on-the-fly in the terminal?

Tags: bash

In a simple script written in bash the variable project declared within the script:

```
project='this_is_it'
echo "this is the $project"
```

how to declare `$project` on-the-fly during the script execution directly in terminal (in the responce to the proposition.. ) with the aim to use it subsequently during the workflow execution (so not to declare it without the script) ?

Comment: Are you looking for the [`read` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-read) (`read -p 'What is the project? ' project`)? Or environment variables?

Comment: Yep the read -p does what I need. What is the second possibility ?

Comment: Define the variable in the environment before executing the script. Comment out the `project` assignment in your script (just put a `#` at the beginning of the line) and type `project=foo ./myscript` on a single line. Or type `export project=foo` and then `./myscript` (assuming the name of your script is `myscript` and you made it executable with `chmod +x myscript`).

Comment: Okay, I gotcha ! Yes actually I've already tried export var=foo in .bashrc function which then executes another sh script using $var, I did not know that this called as environment variable. what is the advantage ??

Comment: The advantage is that environment variables are passed as part of the environment of all child processes. It's one form of parent-to-child process communication and it is frequently useful. In your case, for instance, you could test if `project` is already defined from the environment, else ask the user. So, if your user knows that the project will always be `foo` they can define it once for all instead of answering the same question again and again.

Comment: Right, thank you! Cheers

Comment: but note that changes made in a child process do not update the parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible interpretation of what you are asking -
if you define a variable in front of a command, that variable will be dynamically available for that command, but won't be retained afterwards.

```
$: env|grep foo                    # no foo exists
$: foo=bar env|grep foo            # foo exists only for this command
foo=bar
$: env|grep foo                    # no foo remains 
$: export bar=foo                  # set a value that persists
$: env|grep foo                    # bar's foo exists, but no $foo
bar=foo
$: foo=bar env|grep foo            # this has both, but foo still doesn't persist
foo=bar
bar=foo
$: env|grep foo                    # only bar
bar=foo
$: foo=bar bar=newfoo env|grep foo # overwrites *for this command only*
bar=newfoo
foo=bar
$: env|grep foo                    # back to as it was
bar=foo
```

Be wary of *using* such a variable in the command, however, as the interpreter is not running in the environment that receives the dynamically set variable.

```
$: foo=bar echo "bar=[$bar] foo=[$foo]"           # interpolated before the command
bar=[foo] foo=[]
$: foo=bar bash -c 'echo "bar=[$bar] foo=[$foo]"' # processed BY the command
bar=[foo] foo=[bar]
```